# Error deploying simple docker container to Azure Kubernetes

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, .net-core

I am new to Azure kubernetes.  I'm trying to deploy a simple .net core web api to Azure Kubernetes.  I just created the default weather project in VS 2019.  I am able to run it in Docker locally fine.  I am also able to push the image to a Azure container repository without a problem.

I get the error when I do:

```
kubectl apply -f .\deployment.yml
```

When I run kubectl get pods after the deploy I see this.

> |               NAME               | READY |      STATUS      |
>   RESTARTS | AGE |
>
> | test-deployment-7564d94c8f-fdz9q | 0/1   | ImagePullBackOff |
>   0 | 74s |

so then I ran `kubectl describe pod test-deployment-7564d94c8f-fdz9q`

and these are the errors coming back

> Warning  Failed      (x4 over 15s)  kubelet,
>   aks-agentpool-30270636-vmss000000
>
> Failed to pull image
>   "ipaspoccontreg.azurecr.io/test:dev": [rpc error: code = Unknown desc
>   = image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform, rpc error:code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get
>   https://ipaspoccontreg.azurecr.io/v2/test/manifests/dev: unauthorized:
>   authentication required]

My deployment.yml is

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-container
        image: ipaspoccontreg.azurecr.io/test:dev
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and my service.yml is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: test-pod
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: The error shows the authentication required problem. So you need to add the credential for your deployment. For the ACR, the simplest way is the grant the permission of ACR to the AKS, see the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration?toc=/azure/container-registry/toc.json&bc=/azure/container-registry/breadcrumb/toc.json).

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a secret in Kubernetes which will contain your container registry credentials.